# Should we be getting rid of unversioned tags where there clearly is a version?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't really see a point in questions being double tagged as [brand-product](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/brand-product) [product-version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-version), can we please change these to [brand-product-version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/brand-product-version) as this would cover both tags? What do you think?

Comment: can you cite a few examples from SU and perhaps elsewhere?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel+excel-2007

Answer (score 5):

A versioned tag should automatically include the unversioned tag. This boils down to the introduction of sub-tags.

If someone follows or filters `product` they most likely also want to follow or include in their filtering `product-v4` and `product-v5` - but it would be impractical to have to mention them all for followers and in search.

And on the other hand, it is also simpler for tagging questions, this way only the specific tags have to be added manually.

The relation between `brand-product` and `product` could be handled similar.

To implement this, for each tag one or more parent-tags could be defined. `Brand a` could be a parent of `product 1` and `product 2` could be a parent of `product 2 - v4` and so on.

I see 2 ways how this could be handled in tagging:

a) Whenever a tag that was added has a parent, all parents are automatically added to the tag list. Parents do not count regarding the maxmimum number of tags per question. This way it is more explicit.

b) The other way would be to automatically remove all parent tags, whenever a child is present. But then search and following would have to automatically search for all parent tags of a tag searched for or followed. This way the questions maybe look nicer, but I am not sure if it is obvious for everybody what happens.

Comment: Of course, assuming a common prefix, you can search for tags with wildcards: [http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/micro*](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/micro*), [http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/micro~](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/micro~). See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1726/187228) for details. [Apparently](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/add-ability-to-use-wildcarded-tags-in-search), this only works if the URL is entered manually; it's broken for the search box (and is a reported bug).

Answer (score 2):

1. If the tag is somewhat or possibly ambiguous without the brand prefix, include the prefix.
2. If the tag doesn't need to include the brand, it doesn't need to include the brand.
3. If a question is asking about a product, and isn't specific to a particular version, then it doesn't need to include a version tag.

The brand is usually superfluous unless in the first case. Then you can just go with the product or product version.

Comment: You are again not answering to the question, and repeating yourself as this is your personal reasoning for the recent action you had performed. Other that than I voted to disagree because I think this leads to inconsistency; as simply typing [tag:microsoft] doesn't reveal all auto-complete results nor does the tag list list them together, and questions display odd against each other...

Comment: So your ultimate goal is to have all product tags grouped together by brand? @tom

Comment: Ultimately letting the community decide (which they have already done before), in the case of Microsoft I feel it's necessary to get it standardized and consistent...

Answer (score 2):

I kind of agree with random here, though I do not feel strongly about it; that is …

[product](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product)

… **should be sufficient in the case where the product is unambiguously and uniquely .. itself.** That is, if it is *not* a generic name. Now you could argue that "word" and "access" are not unique enough and that

[brand-product](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/brand-product)

helps. I won't disagree.

However, one thing I do feel strongly about and I agree with Tom: I certainly do NOT want us to have

[brand-product](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/brand-product) [2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/2010)

that is not good, we should simply have

[product-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-2010) or [brand-product-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/brand-product-2010)

Comment: For the third part, I meant that some questions were tagged like [tag:microsoft-excel] [tag:excel-2010], as that leaves a duplicate `excel` in the tag line where [tag:micrrosoft-excel] doesn't add value. As for the last line, I wonder if it's good or bad to have inconsistency between Word or Access, it's something the community has to decide. I'm just saying, they were a mess for a pretty long time and I believe that they still are a bit now. I'm feeling that if we don't handle them now more specific re-tag requests are going to keep showing up for related tags. But well, I'm just asking...