# Tag prefixes (like wireless-networking and networking)

Tags: discussion, tags

I know that there are easy ways to deal with tags like [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) (specifically, [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) includes [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows)). What happens with tags like [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) and [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking)?

It seems like this is a similar case, where a wireless networking question should also fall under networking. However, from what I can tell, [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) and [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) don't have the same relationship as [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) and [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows). How should we be using tags here? Should questions be tagged with both?

Comment: What do mean by *windows-7 includes windows*?

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm referring to answers like [this](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5006/183377).